# Spring mvc on application load event to load collection

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have to load something from the database to initialize a hashMap object that I want to add to a application wide variable that all my mvc controllers can access.

I won't be modifying this object, and I don't care if it can only be updated when the application reloads.

Does spring MVC have a place where I can do this and have spring manage the lifecycle also?

I know servlets has the WebListener annotation:

@WebListener

But not sure if spring has this also (wrapped in their iOc container).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best place is to declare a bean like the following:

```
public class MyInitializingBean {
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        //do initialization here
    }
}
```

Then you declare that bean in your xml file, if you don't like the annotation, there are non-annotation approaches for initializing a bean, but that gets executed when the spring context starts.

Comment: i.e. just like as if it was loaded only once.

Comment: Exactly, by default spring beans are singleton unless you declare them on scope prototype

Comment: where should I store such a bean? like what folder?  I have models, services, controllers, filters.  Where would a bean like this fit in?

Comment: I think the choice you should make depends on what kinds of beans this bean serves :) Personally I'd add it on the service if I need to access the data on the service layer.

Comment: @Blankman If it's a singleton across the entire app, what does the request have to do with it? Just inject it into any Spring object that requires it, in your case, I guess just the controllers?